# Hibernate Remove faulty entity from transaction

Tags: java, hibernate

I have SpringBoot application which uses hibernate to communicate with database. Flow of application is
read xml -> extract entities from xml -> load entities to database. Some of theese entities are not valid so i would like to just skip them. Im using following code

```
public <T extends BaseEntity> long bulkInsert(Collection<T> entities) {
        long count = 0;
        try {
            for (T t : entities) {
                if (t.getId() == null) {
                    entityManager.merge(t);
                    count++;
                }
                if (count > 0 && count % 1000 == 0) {
                    log.debug("Zapisano {}. Przeslanie do bazy.", count);
                    entityManager.flush();
                    entityManager.clear();
                }
            }
            entityManager.flush();
            entityManager.clear();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            for (T ent: entities) {
                entityManager.remove(ent);
            }
            for (T ent: entities) {
                try{
                    entityManager.merge(ent);
                    entityManager.flush();
                    entityManager.clear();
                } catch (Exception ex){
                    entityManager.remove(ent);
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

But i alwaysget errorrs in first catch block. Right now i get

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
```

in line where i try to merge. I also tried persisting again but it generated different error - detached entity passed to persist. Maybe my approach is completely wrong (i`m new with hibernate). What is right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's because your entity have Persist state. Just read more about `Entity Manager` in Hibernate. Example of diagram: https://www.baeldung.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/2016-07-11_13-38-11-1024x551.png